# Script firing twice in Main Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to implement [KonamiJS](http://code.snaptortoise.com/konami-js/) within my AngularJS app that opens up a [BootstrapUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal dialog box when a user hits the Konami code on their keyboard. The script *works*, however it's firing twice and I can't seem to figure out why. This is what I have in my main controller that wraps all of the content on the page so it can be triggered from anywhere. Within the main controller I have an Angular view also:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="main-content" ng-view="" class="content"></div>
</body>


angular.module('App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

      $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
      var credits_page = new Konami();

      credits_page.code = function() {
         $modal.open({
           animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
           templateUrl: 'views/credits.html',
           controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
         });

         console.log("Trigger");
      }

      credits_page.load();
});
```

And then I have a modal controller that this talks to:

```
  angular.module('App')
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

      $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
          };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };
    });
```

And just incase here is my script load order:

```
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/contact.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/particles.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/konami.js"></script>
```

I assume it has something to do with the view switch but I can't put my finger on what exactly is causing it.

Comment: I also had a same problem once and it turned out that I had the Controller assigned in my route config as well as in my HTML attribute i.e., using the `ng-controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have mention `MainCtrl` inside your `$routeProvider` defination, so basically what is happening your `MainCtrl` controller is getting register twice.

You need to remove `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` from the body tag, which basically seems redundant as it instantiating `MainCtrl` twice.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I'll accept the answer once I'm able to.

Comment: @JamesIves Glad to help you..Thanks , :)

Answer (score 0):

check your template and route you may have declare controller twice

**in template:** ng-controller="MainCtrl"

**in route:** controller:'MainCtrl'